# Add node with different attribute in accordance with the condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to optimize my XSLT file to have a better readable code and to avoid repetitions.

In a part, I have a new element that must be added to the DOM (target is HTML) with different attributes, according to the condition.

ex:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="status = 0 or type = 2">
        <img id="img_{$var1}_check" height="14" width="13" src="{$var1}.png" class="{$var1}" onclick="check({$var1})" alt="{$var1}" title="{$var1}"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="status = 1 or type = 24">
        <img id="img_{$var2}_check" height="14" width="13" src="{$var2}.png" class="{$var2}" onclick="check({$var2})" alt="{$var2}" title="{$var2}"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="status = 2 or type = 4">
        <img id="img_{$var3}_check" height="14" width="13" src="{$var3}.png" class="{$var3}" onclick="check({$var3})" alt="{$var3}" title="{$var3}"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="status = 4 or type = 22">
        <img id="img_{$var4}_check" height="14" width="13" src="{$var4}.png" class="{$var4}" onclick="check({$var4})" alt="{$var4}" title="{$var4}"/>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Is there a way to not write the whole `img` element in each "when" ?

Regards

Comment: Can you show more of your XSLT? Where do `$var1` to `$var4` come from? In what way is the `<xsl:choose>` called?

Comment: You may use xsl:call-template or xsl:attribute-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is put your xsl:choose inside a variable, and change the choose just to return either $var1, $var2, $var3 or $var4. Then, write out the **img** element using the value of this new variable

```
<xsl:variable name="imgvar">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="status = 0 or type = 2">
            <xsl:value-of select="$var1" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="status = 1 or type = 24">
            <xsl:value-of select="$var2" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="status = 2 or type = 4">
            <xsl:value-of select="$var3" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="status = 4 or type = 22">
            <xsl:value-of select="$var4" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<img id="img_{$imgvar}_check" height="14" width="13" src="{$imgvar}.png" class="{$imgvar}" onclick="check({$imgvar})" alt="{$imgvar}" title="{$imgvar}"/>
```

I strongly suspect this is not what you want though, because it doesn't seem right to use the same variable in all of the attributes in your **img** element.

Another approach would be to use a named template, and just call this from the xsl:choose

```
<xsl:template name="img">
    <xsl:param name="imgvar">
    <img id="img_{$imgvar}_check" height="14" width="13" src="{$imgvar}.png" class="{$imgvar}" onclick="check({$imgvar})" alt="{$imgvar}" title="{$imgvar}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="imgvar">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="status = 0 or type = 2">
            <xsl:call-template name="img">
                <xsl:with-param name="imgvar" select="$var1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="status = 1 or type = 24">
            <xsl:call-template name="img">
                <xsl:with-param name="imgvar" select="$var2" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="status = 2 or type = 4">
            <xsl:call-template name="img">
                <xsl:with-param name="imgvar" select="$var3" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="status = 4 or type = 22">
            <xsl:call-template name="img">
                <xsl:with-param name="imgvar" select="$var4" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

This can then obviously be extended to use extra parameters if needed.

Another way, is to put the xsl:choose inside the **img** element, and write out different attributes for each choice.

```
    <img height="14" width="13">
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="status = 0 or type = 2">
               <xsl:attribute name="id">img_<xsl:value-of select="$var1" /></xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$var1" />.png</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="status = 1 or type = 24">
               <xsl:attribute name="id">img_<xsl:value-of select="$var2" /></xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$var2" />.png</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="status = 2 or type = 4">
               <xsl:attribute name="id">img_<xsl:value-of select="$var3" /></xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$var3" />.png</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="status = 4 or type = 22">
               <xsl:attribute name="id">img_<xsl:value-of select="$var4" /></xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$var4" />.png</xsl:attribute>
           </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
    </img>
```

I would say using **xsl:call-template** was the best best here.